# shell script read several lines from file A and write them in file B

Tags: shell, sed

hi i'm new to shell and got stuck on this:
i have file A like

```
[area1]

a

b

[area2]

c

d

[area3]

e 

f
```

i want to read the lines in a certain area and append the lines to file B. like for [area2], i'm expecting to read

```
c

d
```

also the area names are random and stored in a variable say $AREA, so i'll also need to match the variable instead of directly using "[area2]", so what i need to cut is from the line equals $AREA to the next line start with "["

how can i achieve this? any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Sed has a write command(`w`) that you can use to redirect output to a file:

```
AREA="area2";
sed '/\['"$AREA"'\]/,/^\[/!d;//d;w B' A
```

- `/\['"$AREA"'\]/,/^\[/!d`: prints lines from your area value up to next line starting with `[`
- `//d`: removes lines matching the addresses(here `[area2]` and `[area3]`)
- `w B`: writes to file B

To append output to file B:

```
sed '/\['"$AREA"'\]/,/^\[/!d;//d;' A >> B
```

Comment: thank you so much!!! is there a way to append the lines to file B? using w seems to overwrite file B each time...

Answer (score 0):

```
a="area2"
sed '/\['"$a"'\]/,+4!d' A|sed '1,2d' >>B
```